# Is it possible to install ros groovy and kinetic together in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have kinetic installed but also need groovy for another project. Is it possible to run groovy in Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257726/is-it-possible-to-install-ros-groovy-and-kinetic-together-in-ubuntu-16.04-lts?/) by [devious_archangel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29797/devious_archangel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it possible to run groovy in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

If you mean: are there binaries provided I could use, then: no.

There is a (perhaps slim, but still) chance that you could get the things that you need to build from sources on 16.04, but there are no guarantees.

What exactly do you think you need Groovy for? Building individual packages from source -- even on newer OS / ROS versions -- is way easier than trying to build an entire ROS release.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [devious_archangel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29797/devious_archangel/) on 2017-03-24**:
Thank you for the reply gvdhoorn, I actually need it for running an old project for testing but it seems groovy is not compatible with the latest version of Ubuntu.

P.S: I am still a beginner in this.